# What does recycling the app pool actually do exactly?

Tags: iis-7, web-server, application-pools

I have had a number of problems in the past that have been solved by simply recycling the app pool.
I am currently getting an error occurring about once every other day (SQL server timeout oddly enough) that will continue persist until the app pool is recycled and so I wondered what does this do exactly?

Many thanks,
Kohan.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The app pool is the webservices deployed on your iis instance. They can either be backend services behind your website or front end webservices. Either way if you are getting a timeout from a SQL server instance it means that these webservices are either losing their connection to the database or it's become non-responsive for that DB session.

By refreshing the pool you are fundamentally restarting the application and re-establishing the DB connection(s).